# php fantasy draft script

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm looking to create a snake draft script. I want the order to go up the array then back down the array.

```
 $teams = array('mike','jim','chris','tim');
```

I want the order to be

```
 Round 1
 Mike, Jim, Chris, Tim
 Round 2
 Tim, Chris, Jim, Mike
```

That would be two rounds. I want that to be the order and repeat that but I cant figure it out with PHP.
I have tried getting the last pick from the draft in my database.
$lastpick = (the last team name submitted to my database);

```
if(empty($lastpick) && $teams(0) == 'mike'){
  //do this
}else if($lastpick == $teams(0) && $teams(1) == 'jim'){
 // do this
}else if($lastpick == $teams(1) && $teams(2) == 'chris'){
  // do this
}else if($lastpick == $teams(2) && $teams(3) == 'tim'){
  // do this
}else if($lastpick == $teams(3) && $teams(3) == 'tim'){
  // do this
}
```

What would i do next? this gets the order mike,jim,chris,tim then tim again but I cant get it to back to the third team in my array.
Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: well it's not very clear what is the rationale behind the order...

Comment: the rationale? its a fantasy snake draft.

Comment: think for instance that not everybody knows what is a "fantasy snake draft" maybe you can explain the sorting algorithm in a clearer way so also the people that don't know the draft can try to help you

Comment: Q. What is a snake draft? A. http://bit.ly/16eX1Hj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you need `&& $teams(x) == 'yyy'` in each statement, you already know what they are because the order is defined, and if they change, you need to update all these statements.

You will need some form of flag to define which way you're currently moving, up or down.

```
boolean movingUp = true;

if(empty($lastpick)) { // first team }
else if(movingUp && $lastpick == $teams(0)) { // second team }
else if(movingUp && $lastpick == $teams(1)) { // third team }
else if(movingUp && $lastpick == $teams(2)) { movingUp = false; // fourth team }
else if(!movingUp && $lastpick == $teams(3)) { // fourth team }
else if(!movingUp && $lastpick == $teams(2)) { // third team }
else if(!movingUp && $lastpick == $teams(1)) { // second team }
else if(!movingUp && $lastpick == $teams(1)) { movingUp = true; $lastpick = null; // first team }
```

You don't need to have a `$lastpick == $teams(3)` because once you have picked the penultimate one you know the next action, whilst moving up, is the last team.

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for. I am adding a while loop and it should work. Thanks a lot mane.